# header() simply does nothing

Tags: php

Only thing I have changed recently is turn register_globals to off

Here is the end of login script:

```
$from = $_POST['from']; //convert form element to var
//echo "got here, from is $from"; die; 

// test to prove $from is empty
if($from == '')
{ 
    $from = '/pages/reg2.html'; 
}
header("Location: $from"); // this should redirect page
```

Comment: unrelated to the header issue but use `empty()` in place of `==''` ie, `if(empty($from))`

Comment: Looks like you have some debug output in the script. Do you know that header() is actually being called?

Comment: @jasonbar no its not, the page simply stays where it is

Comment: Where would I see the error log?

Comment: The problem appears to exist outside of the code you've posted. Can you share more?

Comment: @Darren: Is there actually a space between your two forward slashes in your code?

Comment: Hey Darren, The 2 common causes of this i have experienced are: content already published to page (May be error msg) that would stop the redirect, and also spaces or new lines after php closing tags in this file or any of the included files.

Answer (score 0):

try this code should work

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['from']) && !empty($_POST['from'])) { 
$from = $_POST['from']; //convert form element to var
//echo "got here, from is $from"; die; 

 // test to prove $from is empty
}

if(empty($from))

{ 
    $from = '/pages/reg2.html'; 
}

//if still doesnt work try to replace this line with : echo $from; exit(); 
//just for you to know at what point you are .
header("Location: $from");
exit();




?>
```